# Check for existing object element or: How to check if user is in min one of multiple group

Tags: javascript, object, meteor, roles

Is it possible to make this a little bit shorter / easier?

I'm using `alanning:roles` with **groups**. Now I need to check if a user is logged in and the user is in the **group** `admin` or `editor`.

This is what I am doing (as `isInRole` is checking for the role, not for the group).

```
const loggedInUser = Meteor.user();
if (!loggedInUser || !loggedInUser.roles.hasOwnProperty('admin') || !loggedInUser.roles.hasOwnProperty('editor'))
    throw new Meteor.Error(403, "Access denied", "You don't have access");
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this:

```
if (!loggedInUser || _.intersection(loggedInUser.roles, ["admin", "editor"]).length > 0)
```

But I'd use the built-in functions of `Roles` for role management:

```
if (Roles.getRolesForUser(Meteor.userId()).some(x => _.contains(["admin", "editor"], x)))
```